# How to show white paper (data) pdf file before download this file

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I have a function to show PDF . its triggered by click button to show/download pdf .

this function can show/displayed this data (before download) if i using **php artisan serve** , but now i not using **php artisan serve** because of BUG on my datatables , so i using XAMPP .

if i clicking button to download ,its not displaying data, its download automaticly .

how i can solved this ?

```
public function PDF(Request $request,$id){
    $users = User::findOrFail($id);

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.pdf',['users' => $users]);
    return $pdf->stream('Profile.pdf', array('Attachment'=>0));              
}
```

its my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please mention `header`

```
$pdf->stream('Profile.pdf')
           ->header('Content-Type','application/pdf');
```

Please check your carome setting as well.

1) On your computer, **open Chrome.**

2) At the top right, click More **Settings**.

3) At the bottom, click Advanced.

4) Under "Privacy and security," click Site **settings**.

5) Near the bottom, click **PDF** documents.

6) **Turn on** Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome.

Comment: Not changed sir ,

Comment: Have you check your carome setting?

Comment: I set like this site your recomended , i set chrome ,i set firefox but didnt have a some different

Comment: Please check @FabryProg comment of setting header try it out hope you get help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113562/open-pdf-in-a-new-tab-using-dompdf

I think you might have problem with `headers` or  `('Attachment'=>0)`

Comment: u know , i turn off it and its work . what just happen ? if its on , its doesnt work

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think this might be something that must be set by a browser setting. [How to update pdf browser settings](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001114.htm)

Comment: I set this but still didnt work . I think this problem is i using Xampp . If i using artisan serve its can previewed